# How to determine completion?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am creating currency rates website backend in node js with MongoDB and MySQL,

At first I am storing data into MongoDB from API and afterwards, for saving RAM and CPU I have decided to create and store analytical data into MySQL.

Please look at following code,

```
    update24HRateArr: () => {
    var da = [];
    db.query('TRUNCATE TABLE `rate24h`', (xerr, xres) => {
        if (xerr) console.log(xerr.message);
    });

    mdb.currency((currList) => {
        if (currList && currList.length > 0) {
            currList.length = 50;

            for (var c = 0; c < currList.length; c++) {

                mdb.rateArr(currList[c], '24h', (data) => {

                    if (data && data.length > 0) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            var tmp = [];

                            tmp.push(data[i].id);//1->id
                            tmp.push(i);//2->number
                            tmp.push(data[i].time);//3->time value
                            tmp.push(data[i].price_usd);//4->price usd
                            tmp.push(data[i].price_btc);//5->price btc
                            tmp.push(data[i].price_inr);//6->price inr
                            tmp.push(fn.time.unix());//7->DB update time

                            da.push(tmp);
                        }
                        //main area for done call

                        /*
                        if (da.length == 1200) {

                            db.query('INSERT INTO `rate24h` VALUES ?', [da], (err, datax) => {
                                if (err) console.log(err);
                                else {
                                    console.log(`${fn.time.timeStamp()} Data(${datax.affectedRows}) Inserted for Rate24H`);
                                }
                            });
                            console.log(da);
                        }*/
                        console.log(`inside i ${da.length}`);
                    }
                    console.log(`inside iRateArr ${da.length}`);
                });
                //console.log(`inside c ${da.length}`); <- always 0 no way 
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log('Currency Loading failed');
        }
    });
},
```

Now, I know that length of da var is gonna be 1200 in this case because 50 currencies and 24 hours but in some cases it's flexible,

I can't exactly determine when this **da var** updating will be completed via for loops so I can execute insert query to mysql

that if(da.length ===1200) is not enough I need exact point that I can execute INSERT query.

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like you need to use Promises. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your problem correctly, but would `if ((da.length >= 1200) or (c = currList.length) {` not solve your problem? You would have to move it outside of the `if (data && data.length > 0) {`, and you would have to reset `da` after the insert, and I am not entirely sure why you set the length to 50. Or, as I said, if I understood your problem at all (as e.g. greg understood something completely different).

Comment: @Solarflare I am cutting that array's length to 50, just look this problem as when this arary "da" will be contains all data.

Comment: Yes, if I understood your problem correctly, my proposal should work regardless of the 50. I was (and still am) just unsure if I understood your problem correctly (e.g. because of things like the 50).

Comment: Just find a way that when array da will have all data pushed through for loop